# Unwanted caching of web page

Tags: php, html

I have a problem of web pages being cached even though I specify that it should not. Take the simple example :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
</head>
<?php
    print date("Y/m/d H:i:s");
?>
</html>
```

Hitting refresh several times in my browser indicates that this page is not reloaded as the time stays the same. It will eventually refresh if I keep on hitting the refresh button in the browser. Where could this page be cached and how can I avoid it?

I'm using Apache 2.2.15, PHP 5.3.2 on openSuse 11.2, and my testing browser is Firefox 3.5.7 on the same machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the no caching headers? e.g.:

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
?>
```

Comment: A `<meta>` tag is different than an HTTP header, though I'm not sure which takes precedence. Do a `curl -I http://example.com/` from the command line to check HTTP cache headers.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I tried setting the headers, but it also doesn't work. curl -I give :
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 15 Apr 2010 10:07:56 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) PHP/5.3.2
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.2
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/html

Comment: Try curl or wget and request the page and see if the html changes. If it does then you have some serious browser caching issues. Also, make sure firefox is not working in offline mode ;)

Comment: It works correctly with curl and wget. It definately seems to be a Firefox issue. Firefox is not in offline mode, it does actually refresh if I hit the refresh button 20 times or more. Should I maybe ask this question in a Firefox mailing list?

Comment: Hmmm. Try upgrading/installing it again before you do that.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips. This is definitely a Firefox issue, and as such does not belong here. Starting Firefox in safe mode does not present this problem. I didn't find anything googling, so I'll just try to upgrade. Thanks.